A BW movie about WWII
I'm looking for a movie in black and white that was probably produced around 1970. The story is in an Eastern European country occupied by Germans with a two story house where a young lady lives in first floor and a German officer on the second floor.
Every night, the German officer comes down and talks to young lady while she is knitting. The words spoken by the German officer are deep and philosophical while the lady just sits and knits and listens.
After a few months the German officer moves to another field and the story ends.
I saw it dubbed but guess it was originally in English. Also the knitting at the end of the movie finds out to be two hands trying to reach each other.

I know what you're looking for, but the film's country\language will really help me out as there are many versions out there, in different languages.

@walt I saw it dubbed but guess it was originally in English. Also the knitted at the end of movie finds out to be two hands trying to reach each other.

And it was definitely feature-length?

This sounds like an adaptation of the novel The Silence of the Sea, most likely Melville's from 1949.

In a small town in occupied France in 1941, the German officer, Werner Von Ebrennac is billeted in the house of the uncle and his niece. The uncle and niece refuse to speak to him, but each evening the officer warms himself by the fire and talks of his country, his music, and his idealistic views of the relationship between France and Germany. That is, until he visits Paris and discovers what is really going on...

The niece knits in silence as he talks about these things every night, and eventually he moves on. Now, the novel was adapted many times, but AFAIK, this is the only feature-length one in B&W. Here's a clip about the film (and if it's not what you remembered, here are the other adaptations):



